# Getting a RangeError: Invalid Time Value when using React datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I have set up a DatePicker component using the react-datepicker library and am passing it an initial date value calculated using today's date in the MM-DD-YYYY format.

However, when I load the page in React, I get

> RangeError: Invalid Time Value

```
const AuthForm = ({ buttonText, formType, onAuth, history, ...props }) => {

  const startDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString();

  const initialStateSignup = {
      email : "",
      password : "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      gender: "",
      dob: startDate
  };
    const [state , setState] = useState(formType === 'login' ? initialStateLogin : initialStateSignup);

  const handleChange = e => {
      const {name , value} = e.target;
      setState( prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          [name] : value
      }))
  }
  ...
  return (
     <DatePicker
        placeholderText="Date of Birth"
        selected={state.dob}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
  )
```

Where is this error coming from? I console logged the startDate and it looks valid to me, and this is the method I have seen documented in other threads for generating the start date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just pass to your DatePicker component `dateFormat="MM-DD-YYYY"` prop, with your desired format.

https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-7

```
<DatePicker
  dateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy"
  selected={this.state.startDate}
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
/>
```

P.D. You would like to use `useReducer` instead of `useState` in the case your state is an object.

Answer (score 20):

According to this post https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/1752 you most probably use old version of datepicker, that also may not be fully consistent with your React environment.

So check your react-datepicker version, if needed upgrade to 2+, and use this syntax:

```
const selected = moment(isoDateStr).toDate();
```

This is because react-datepicker before version 2 uses moment object date type directly and 
version 2+ uses javascript date type instead.

Answer (score 5):

use new Date(this.state.StartDate)

```
  <DatePicker
  dateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy"
  selected={new Date(this.state.startDate)}
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of Adolfo and Vijay's answers worked for me:

`Start Date:<br></br><DatePicker dateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy" selected={new Date()} onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)} /><br></br>`

`End Date:<br></br><DatePicker dateFormat="MM-dd-yyyy"  selected={new Date()} onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)} /><br></br>`

Answer (score 0):

This problem are very simple way to solve.
Your reactjs project inside install react datepicker and moment js like

```
    yarn add react-datepicker
    or npm install react-datepicker
    yarn add moment
    or npm install moment
```

And import your component page like

```
    import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
    import moment from 'moment';
    function Car() {
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());  
    const slectedDate = moment(yourDate).toDate();
      return (
     <DatePicker
                className="form-control"
                placeholderText="Select date"
                onChange={(date) => field.onChange(date, setStartDate(date))}
                selected={slectedDate }
                dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
              />
);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It can be done with react date picker only.

On the loading of page or in componentDidMount() function , you can set the state of date by formatting as using dateformat or be with new Date()

console.log(localStorage.getItem("valuationDate"));
var startDateStore = **dateFormat**(localStorage.getItem("valuationDate"), "dd mmm yyyy");
    console.log(startDateStore);
    
    this.setState({
      startDate: new Date(localStorage.getItem("valuationDate")),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I experienced was because my redux state initialized a none date string.
The value of that string was: "loading".

Once I changed "loading" to "2000-01-01T00:00:00Z" it all worked.

Basically my initial state of the datepicker was invalid. **No need for MomentJS**, just make sure your values are correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { DayPicker } from 'react-day-picker';
import 'react-day-picker/dist/style.css';

const Daypiker = () => {
    const [selected,setSelected]=useState(new Date())
    return (
        <div>
            <DayPicker
            mode='single'
            selected={selected}
           onSelect={(data)=>{
                      if(data){
                      setSelected(data)
                       }}}   
            ></DayPicker>

            <p><p>You selected {format(selected, 'PP')}.</p></p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Daypiker;
```

Comment: I stumbled on this problem with a WordPress bespoke gutenberg plugin (thanks @josias) that uses DatePicker. What would be the way to adapt the gb cmeta code to have this working in a swiss-date-format style?